# Add numbers between start and end and find rest of division of sum

Tags: java, sum, modulo

Hey StackOverflow community.

I have a problem with my homework and hence do not expect you guys to literally solve it for me, but I've been struggling with this particular question for 5 days now and I don't really see what I'm doing wrong. We're meant to add all the numbers between start and end and divide that sum by a given divisor, if the result of this division is 0, the program should give out true, if not then false using `System.out.println()`.

I know this is a very simple issue but its my second week so i'm not too familiar with all Java functions yet. This is what I got but it doesn't give me any answer at all. I'd appreciate if you could maybe point out where I went wrong. Thank you guys in advance!

```
public class EX6 {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    {
    }
    int divisor = 14;
    int start = 42;
    int end = 678;
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    i= 42;
    while (i<=end) sum= start +start++; i++;
    if (sum % divisor == 0) {System.out.println(true);
    } else{
    System.out.println(false);
} }}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of `sum = start + start++` I think you want `sum = sum + start++`. You want to add to a running total, not set `sum` equal to `start + start + 1`.

Second, `println` needs to be passed a string (`"true"`, not `true`).

Also, it is not exactly a bug but there is no need for the variable `i`. If you think through it, `i` is always equal to `start`, so you can just reference `start` instead of `i`.

```
public class EX6 {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int divisor = 14;
        int start = 42;
        int end = 678;
        int sum = 0;

        while (start <= end) {
            sum = sum + start++; 
        }

        if (sum % divisor == 0) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else{
            System.out.println("false");
        } 
    }
}
```

A small note about your original code: it is always good practice to put a bracket around the code you want to execute in a loop. For example, in your code, `while (i<=end) sum= start +start++; i++;`, the `i++` is not part of the loop because there are no brackets. So the problem will probably run forever. To fix this statement you would just use:

```
while (condition) {
    //statement 1
    //statement 2
    //statement 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
int divisor = 14;
int start = 42;
int end = 678;
int sum = 0;
int i;
while (start<=end){
 sum+=start; 
 start = start++;
}
if (sum % divisor == 0) {
   System.out.println(true);
} else{
   System.out.println(false);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. It sets sum = start + start on every iteration of the loop. So at the end sum will just be 678 + 678. Not the right answer.

Comment: Apologies, My typo error... I will be changing it to Sum+=start;